# Getting Error "Call to a member function formName() on a non-object"

Tags: php, yii2

I'm getting error (Call to a member function formName() on a non-object) while trying to get data from tabular input. Here's my code -

**View Code:**

```
$arr = array("config", "specs");
foreach($arr as $index=>$value){
    echo '<h3>' . $value . '</h3>';
    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    echo '<div class="text-row">';
        echo $form->field($configmodel, "[$index]config[$i]")->label(false);
        echo '<p class="invisible"></p>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

**Controller Code:**

```
$configmodel = new ConfigForm();
$configmodels = [new ConfigForm()];
for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $configmodels[] = new ConfigForm();
}

if($configmodel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    if(Model::loadMultiple($configmodels, Yii::$app->request->post()) &&  Model::validateMultiple($configmodels)){
        return $this->render('result', [
            'configmodels' => $configmodels
        ]);
    }

} else {
    return $this->render('index', [
        'configmodel' => $configmodel
    ]);
}
```

**Model Code:**

```
class ConfigForm extends Model
{
    public $config = [];

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['config', 'required'],
            ['config', 'each', 'rule' => ['string', 'min' => 20]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any calls to `formName()`?

Comment: But I'm getting "PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException | Call to a member function formName() on a non-object". Can u please check my view code and suggest how to get values from those inputs.

Comment: The error says you are calling a function called `formName()` on a non-object but I don't see you calling `formName()`. Does it not say what file and line the error is on?

Comment: show problem  in C:\wamp\www\yii2test\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php

Comment: $formName = $first->formName(); inside public static function loadMultiple($models, $data, $formName = null){}

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Yii, but you can just work backwards from there to find why formName() is being called on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a model instead of an array into [`loadMultiple`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#loadMultiple()-detail). From the guide:

> $models : array : The models to be populated. Note that all models should have the same class.

The same goes for [`validateMultiple`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#validateMultiple()-detail).

Since you are expecting 3 models you can create an array of these:

```
$configModels = [new ConfigForm(), new ConfigForm(), new ConfigForm()];
...
if (Model::loadMultiple($configModels, Yii::$app->request->post()) &&  Model::validateMultiple($configModels)  ...
```

Comment: Hi topher, thanks for answewr. I've updated the code according to your suggestion but still it is not working. Please checkout my updated code.

Comment: No the previous error has gone. Now getting blank page, nothing displayed. Is there any problem in my controller code.

Comment: Hi topher, i solved this problem. One last issue i'm facing is min string length validation for config array value is not working. Please check my updated model code.